# C# refresh DataGridView when updating or inserted on another form

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have 2 forms which are `form A` and `form B`,

`form A` allowes user to insert and update student information.

`form b` is only a DataGridView and button there.

When I insert student on `form A`, then I go to `form B`, the new student did not show on the DataGridView , and if I rerun the program, the new student will appear in `form B`.

I tried using this on button on form b

```
datagridview1.refresh();
datagridview1.update();
```

but it's still not working.

---

Edited:

My code for inserting a worker

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into FWINFOS (ID,Name,Gender,DateOfBirth,Race,WorkingPlace,PassportNO,DateOfExpire,[Position],Photo) values('" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker2.Value + "',@Position,@Photo)", con);


        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position", comboBox1.SelectedText.ToString());
        conv_photo();

        con.Open();
        int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        if (n > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Inserted");
            loaddata();

            rno++;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("No Insert");



    }
```

my `Datagridview1(Form2)` doesn't automatically update when I inserted a new worker. But if I rerun the application, the new worker appears.

Comment: raise a event in form 2, handle it in form 1 and retrieve the data for your gridview again

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer, can i have example?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
// Form A
public void loaddata()
{
    //do what you do in load data in order to update data in datagrid
}
```

then on Form B define:

```
// Form B
FormA obj = (FormA)Application.OpenForms["FormA"];

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    obj.loaddata();
    datagridview1.Update();
    datagridview1.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: So i have to create a button on form A.. is it got any other way?

Comment: you have to trigger an event on form A that new data enter so the datagrid must be updated...that must be done in Form A...

Comment: you can declare the variables of the student you store in Form A as public static and pass it in to Form B when you hit the button in Form B

Comment: Sorry, seriously i dont understand, can i have some example?

Comment: @apomena, can u add me on skype or msn?

Comment: I am on job at the moment..I can give my skype account but I can't talk at the moment

Comment: I want to show you my coding on teamviewer.. so that you can understand my situation.. :(

Comment: post your full code so I can see it...As well as others and it will be easier to find the solution...

Comment: I personally will have a look later hours because I am out work at the moment

Comment: FormA obj=(FormA).Application.current.FormA
error for this one

Comment: FormA obj = (FormA)Application.OpenForms["FormA"];

Comment: This means you reload all of the data... shouldn't DataBinding help in this case?

Answer (score 5):

[`DataGridView.Refresh`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx) and And [`DataGridView.Update`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update.aspx) are methods that are inherited from Control. They have to do with redrawing the control which is why new rows don't appear.

My guess is the data retrieval is on the Form_Load. If you want your Button on Form B to retrieve the latest data from the database then that's what you have to do whatever Form_Load is doing.

A nice way to do that is to separate your data retrieval calls into a separate function and call it from both the From Load and Button Click events.

Answer (score 5):

For datagridview in C#, use this code

```
con.Open();
MySqlDataAdapter MyDA = new MySqlDataAdapter();
string sqlSelectAll = "SELECT * from dailyprice";
MyDA.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(sqlSelectAll, con);

DataTable table = new DataTable();
MyDA.Fill(table);

BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
bSource.DataSource = table;


dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
con.Close();
```

It works for show new records in the datagridview.

Comment: What worked for me was calling the .Fill() method of the DataAdapter (didn't need anything else to cause the refresh of the DataGridView). Make sure you set the ClearBeforeFill property appropriately before calling Fill.

Answer (score 5):

**for refresh data gridview in any where you just need this code:**

```
datagridview1.DataSource = "your DataSource";
datagridview1.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 4):

my datagridview is editonEnter mode . so it refresh only after i leave cell or after i revisit and exit cell twice.

to trigger this iimedately .  i unfocus from datagridview . then refocus it.

```
 this.SelectNextControl(dgv1,true,true,false,true);    
 Application.DoEvents();    //this does magic
 dgv1.Focus();
```

Answer (score 2):

putting a quick example, should be a sufficient starting point

Code in Form A

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> RowAdded;

private void btnRowAdded_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // insert data
     // if successful raise event
     OnRowAddedEvent();
}

private void OnRowAddedEvent()
{
     var listener = RowAdded;
     if (listener != null)
         listener(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Code in Form B

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var frm = new Form2();
     frm.RowAdded += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(frm_RowAdded);
     frm.Show();
}

void frm_RowAdded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // retrieve data again
}
```

You can even consider creating your own `EventArgs` class that can contain the newly added data. You can then use this to directly add the data to a new row in DatagridView

Comment: after your `MessageBox.Show("Inserted");` call the `OnRowAddedEvent();`

Make sure you subscribe to the event in the other form

Comment: can we talk on skype or msn? 
skype : JKT
msn : junkai2595@hotmail.com

Comment: void frm_RowAdded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // retrieve data again <=== what should i put for this
}

Comment: sorry about the delay, you need to put the logic of binding the datagrid again here - so whatever method you called to fill the grid needs to be called again.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the exactly same thing.

```
  public static bool update = false;
  Timer t = null;
  private void RefreshTable()
  {
     t = new Timer();
     t.Interval = 1000;
     t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
     t.Enabled = true;
  }

  void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (update)
        {
           dataGridView.Rows.Clear();
           dataGridView.Refresh();
           setCustomerDetailsTable();
           update = false;
        }
   }
```

I am using a static variable in the form that contains the dataGridView and access it from form A. when user insert or update details I set the `update` variable `true` so that when the next time timer ticks the table updates and set the
`update` as false. That prevent it from updating everytime timer ticks. The `setCustomerDetailsTable()` is the function that initialy loads the data on Form_Load in my case. I am sure this is not the best way. However I am using this timer to show the clock on the UI as well. So I assign it this task as well. When I call `RefreshTable()` on Form_Load it does what I wanted.

Answer (score -1):

Create a small function and use it anywhere

```
public SqlConnection con = "Your connection string"; 
public void gridviewUpdate()
{
    con.Open();
    string select = "SELECT * from table_name";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(select, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "table_name");
    datagridview.DataSource = ds;
    datagridview.DataMember = "table_name";
    con.Close();
}
```