# Unable to refresh DataGridView after updating database

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I've created a drag and drop DataGridView in Visual Studio 2013 and then bound it to a dataset using wizard. 
My problem is when I update the data in the database, the `DataGridView` does not get refreshed.

I have used this code : how ever data binding of the same Form's textboxes get refreshed and updated.

```
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

and

```
dataGridView.Update();
```

EDIT: 
this code also doesnt work :

```
private void toolStripButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bindingSource1.ResetBindings(true);                                 
    }
```

Comment: Refresh your database after updates done

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526067/c-sharp-refresh-datagridview-when-updating-or-inserted-on-another-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code worked write for me, first you should call the GetChanges() method on your data-set, then call the Fill(dataset.dataTable) on your dta-adapter.

```
            secaloFormulaDataSet.GetChanges();
            materialPriceTableAdapter.Fill(secaloFormulaDataSet.materialPrice);
```

this will immediately updates your datagridview and other controls that use data binding in your form.