# When I change the cell value in DataGridView it does not display the value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to change a DataGridView cell value, and I can do it but cell value doesn't shown in DataGridView.

Here is the code;

```
Products.DataSource = productItems.DefaultView; // In here I assign the dataTable to the dataGridView.

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in Products.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells["ProductCode"].Value != null)
            {
                row.Cells["ProductName"].Value = sqlTrans.GetProductNameWithProductCode(row.Cells["ProductCode"].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
```

When I debug, I can see the value is assigned correctly but I can't see the value in dataGridView.

I already tried RefreshEdit, EndEdit, InvalidateCell and Refresh.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
After struggle few more hours, I solve this problem like this;
- After filling the DataTable with SqlDataAdapter, I added a new column named "ProductName" and then fill this column.
- And then I bound this DataTable into the DataGridView.

Comment: You have to call bind method

Comment: Thank you Emanuel, but wihch method is this?

Comment: You are welcome, try gridview1.databind()

Comment: There is no DataBind() method in my dataGridView, I researched this method and find out this method only for web forms. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'm sorry man, i forgot to read the label "winform".

Comment: No problem man, thank you anyway.

Comment: Perhaps try Update and then Refresh, [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526067/c-sharp-refresh-datagridview-when-updating-or-inserted-on-another-form)

Comment: Thank you Milana, I also tried that and didn't help.

Comment: Instead of editing your answer into your question post, please use the button below labelled `Answer Your Question`.