# why does DataGridView show update a step behind

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, event-handling, synchronous

I have a winform that includes a `DataGridView` and a `Button` among a few other controls. I'm adding and removing datagridview's columns and rows manually. A `RefreshContent()` method iterates through some arrays and update the datagridview through the following

```
datagridview.Columns[i].Name = somestring;
```

or

```
datagridview.Rows.Add(someobject);
```

`RefreshContent()` is called in an event handler `OnButtonClick`, bond to the button I mentioned above.
Problem is that I click the button and nothing happens to the datagridview, until I interact with another control. It's like the datagridview shows data update a step behind...I even tried adding this to the end of my event handler:

```
private void OnButtonClick(object s, EventArgs e)
{
  // .... some code
  RefreshContent();
  var ds = dataGridView1.DataSource;
  dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
  dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
  dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

To no avail. I'm not very good at winforms.

Comment: Can [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526067/c-sharp-refresh-datagridview-when-updating-or-inserted-on-another-form/15526208) about refreshing DataGridView help?

Comment: @SeanSkelly no still one step behind...

Comment: What type is the data source? Can you also try dataGridView1.Update() which causes redraw?

Comment: @OguzOzgul yes i have. no luck. it's so strange...

Comment: The code you have shown has some major logic conflicts.  `datagridview.Rows.Add(someobject);` makes no sense unless **someobject** is either a DataGridViewRow instance or an object array.  Assuming that statement does not throw an error, then manipulating  `dataGridView1.DataSource` is pointless as it must be null.  You can not programmatically add rows to the DGV.Rows collection if the DGV is databound.  Since you have not answered @OguzOzgul question about the data source, can we assume that there is none?  I think it would be best if you posted all of RefreshContent method.

Comment: @TnTinMn yes my `someobject` is an object array. you are right the datasource is likely none. I have about zero knowledge on this but I'm starting a winform as a plugin to another app. `RefreshContent` has some native methods and I might need to somehow block this winform thread until those methods are done...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the `RefreshContent` calls another method that updates an array that is passed into `RefreshContent` as an argument, without a `ref`. `RefreshContent` doesn't see the change. Therefore it does not really refresh the datagridview.

**Remember folks, arrays are typically passed in by value**, not reference, unless with `ref` (c#)